# Yii model tbl_* creates TblUserController and tblUser View

Tags: naming-conventions, yii

I am trying to follow (loosely I might add) the [blog tutorial, "Building a Blog System using Yii"](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/).

I call the SQL tables `tbl_user tbl_role` etc as described in the tutorial but the controller ends up being `TblUserController` and the view folder is called `tblUser tblRole`.

In the tutorial only the models take the table prefix, the controller and view does not.

Something is changing and I don't know where. Seems Yii is adding some kind of naming convention or the naming convention present is out of order. It is probably because I am working off the svn trunk.

Does anyone know where this is going, so I can stay within the Yii standards?

Answer (score 2):

You can define table prefix when using Gii. In your case you need to set it to `tbl_`. Then it should generate `UserController` instead of `TblUserController`.